# Magento 2 what is "each" argument and how it works?

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs

what is "each" argument and how it works ?

```
<each args="getRegion('address-list')" render="" />
<each args="getRegion('address-list-additional-addresses')" render="" />
```

If anyone knows please explain.

i know getRegion,need to know how "each" works in magento2

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124584/magento-2-whats-an-each-tag?answertab=active#tab-top